# Creating a column with a set replicates the set n times

Tags: python, pandas, set

I encountered this unexpected behavior using pandas that I don't quite know how to explain, and have not found any related questions here in SO.

When creating a dataframe from a dictionary of lists, as expected we get each element from the iterable into a new row in the columns specified by the given `key`:

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})

   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

However, trying to do the same with a `set`, produced:

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':{1,2,3}})

       a
0  {1, 2, 3}
1  {1, 2, 3}
2  {1, 2, 3}
```

So it seems that the set was replicated up to the amount of elements it actually contains, i.e 3.

I know it does not really make sense to use a set for this, since sets are by definition *unordered collections*. However I could not find any references or explanations behind this behaviour. Is this specified somewhere in the docs? Is there an obvious reason behind this that I'm missing?

```
pd.__version__
# '1.0.0'
```

Comment: Weird, can confirm that version `0.25.3` does the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in [`extract_index`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/29d6b0232aab9576afa896ff5bab0b994760495a/pandas/core/internals/construction.py#L350-L352), and also somewhat [`sanitize_array`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/29d6b0232aab9576afa896ff5bab0b994760495a/pandas/core/construction.py#L388). To give the full walk-through:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.internals.construction import init_dict

#pd.DataFrame({'a':{1,2,3}})
data = {'a': {1,2,3}}
index = None
columns = None
dtype = None
```

Construction from a dict will go through this block

```
elif isinstance(data, dict):
    mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
```

And you can see the index is incorrect:

```
BlockManager
Items: Index(['a'], dtype='object')
Axis 1: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=4, step=1)
ObjectBlock: slice(0, 1, 1), 1 x 4, dtype: object
```

This happens because [`init_dict` does this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/29d6b0232aab9576afa896ff5bab0b994760495a/pandas/core/internals/construction.py#L242-L254), which passes `arrays=[{1, 2, 3}]` to [`extract_index`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/29d6b0232aab9576afa896ff5bab0b994760495a/pandas/core/internals/construction.py#L331-L352) and pandas considers a set to be `list_like`. This means it takes the [length of this set as your Index length](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/29d6b0232aab9576afa896ff5bab0b994760495a/pandas/core/internals/construction.py#L350-L352).

```
from pandas.core.dtypes.common import is_list_like

is_list_like({1,2,3})
#True
```

---

The other issue is due to the difference in `ndim` of an array that stores lists or a set, so the underlying `np.array` is created differently. This is pretty buried [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/29d6b0232aab9576afa896ff5bab0b994760495a/pandas/core/construction.py#L451-L465)

```
np.array({1,2,3}).ndim
#0

np.array([1,2,3]).ndim
#1
```

And so, the set is treated as a "scalar" which gets broadcast to the entire RangeIndex specified above to become `array([{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}], dtype=object)`, while the list remains as `array([1, 2, 3])`

---

Because it has an issue extracting the index, the simple work-around is to specify the index so it doesn't go through any of those.

```
pd.DataFrame({'a': {1,2,3}}, index=[0])
#           a
#0  {1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: Sorry I want to give this a good look, but don't have much time right now. I'll get back to you soon. Thanks a lot in the mean time :-)

Comment: It is quite insightful to see what is being done in the last link you share. Basically `construct_1d_arraylike_from_scalar` will be called, which since treating the value as a `scalar`, seems like it will broadcast its value up to `length`, which will be using the index length?

Comment: @yatu yeah. Probably a mess because they do `getattr(val, "ndim", 1) == 1` so when `val` is `{1,2,3}` it won't have an ndim, but gets the default of 1 so it goes through that clause and likely shouldn't, and then later that is a mistake because the `ndim` of the numpy.array({1,2,3}) is not 1.

Comment: Hmm I see. That was a very good catch! My opinion is that in such case the seems to be buggy. Not that defining a dataframe with a dictionary of sets makes the most sense, but in any case, the behavior is clearly unexpected

Comment: @yatu I agree. Especially because `pd.DataFrame({'a': {1}, 'b': {1,2}})` will yell about a length mis-match in the error, though we know that it will just treat them as scalars anyway when broadcasting. Might be worth making a bug report, I don't have the time  at the moment.

Comment: There's been a PR to fix this issue, seems that the solution will be build a list from the set: `if isinstance(data, set):  data = list(data)`